# nginxにてgetパラメータ値で判断して別サーバ(別プロセス)に処理を渡したい

Tags: nginx

こんにちは。
nginxにて、httpリクエストのgetパラメータの値を判定し、
別のプロセスを呼び出す方法について質問させてください。

前提条件：
・osはlinux(Ubuntu 7.5.0)
・nginxは、port8080で起動しています
・外部からのHTTPリクエストをnginx(port8080)が受け取る
・nginxは、getパラメータの値を参照して、別のプロセスに(port8081,8082)に処理渡したい。
・Pythonのtornadoプロセス(port8081,8082)は、nginxからリクエストを受け取る。
・最終的な処理結果をnginxからレスポンスする

やりたいこと詳細：
nginxが、外部からリクエスト「http://localhost:8080?id=API022」のように受信したら、
GETパラメータの値「API022」の部分を判定して、使用するプロセス選択したいと思います。

①アクセスが「http://localhost:8080?id=API022」だったら
ローカルサーバー「127.0.0.1:8081」のポート8081にhttpリクエストを渡す。

②アクセスが「http://localhost:8080?id=API022」以外だったら
ローカルサーバー「127.0.0.1:8082」のポート8082にhttpリクエストを渡す。

上記のようにGetパラメータによって、処理を分けたいと思い、以下のように「nginx.conf」を編集しました。

「nginx.conf」の内容

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #access_log off;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/debug.log;

    gzip on;

    upstream uwsgi_vox_server_backend {
        server unix:///var/run/uwsgi/web.sock;
        keepalive 65;
    }


    server {
        listen 8080 default_server;


            #使用するポートの設定
            set $backend01 "127.0.0.1:8081";
            set $backend02 "127.0.0.1:8082";    
        
            #API022があれば、「127.0.0.1:8081」を呼び出すようにしたい
            location ~* ^.*API022.$ {
                #rewrite /fugadir/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://$backend01;
                #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
            }   
        
            location ~ ^/.*$ {
                #root /var/www/html/;
                proxy_pass http://$backend02;
            }


    }
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name jp-dev.vvv.io;
        access_log off;
        uwsgi_intercept_errors on;
        location ~ ^/.*$ {
            if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "https") {
                set $http on;
            }
            uwsgi_pass uwsgi_vox_server_backend;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_param HTTPS $http if_not_empty;
            uwsgi_param HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID $request_id;
            uwsgi_param HTTP_X_REQUEST_BODY $request_body;
        }
    }
}
```

しかし、
「http://localhost:8080?id=API022」
でアクセスしても、
「127.0.0.1:8082」の方にリクエストが渡されてしまいます(tornado側のログで確認)。
API022でアクセスがある場合は、「127.0.0.1:8081」側に処理を渡してほしいです。

「location ~ ^.*API022.$ {」
の部分で、「API022」だったら「127.0.0.1:8081」にアクセスできる想定でしたが、
「127.0.0.1:8082」の方に処理(リクエスト)されます。

もしなにか分かることがありましたらご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

クエリストリングは `location` では判別できません。
`$args` 変数で参照できますので、`location / { ... }` の中で if 文で分岐するといいと思います。

```
location / {
    if ($args ~* id=API022) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
    if ($args !~* id=API022) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！実際に適用してみたところ、
想定通りの動きになりました。助かりました！